# Submitting a Silverlight based form from Python (maybe with JS?)

Tags: javascript, python, forms, silverlight, selenium

I know this question sounds really suspicious, but I'm in a weird situation where I've taken control of a project, but the original vendor that built the website retains ownership of the server and the server-side code.

I've successfully scripted a lot of my interactions with the website through Selenium, but one of the activities I need to script is to submit files through a Silverlight form. From what I understand, you can't interact directly with Silverlight from Python or with Selenium, but looking at the source code it looks like the Silverlight is just used to get a file location and display a loading bar, and the actual form submission is done via post to an ASP server-side script. But it has several hidden validation fields.

So I'm kind of envisioning a path where I navigate to this page with Selenium, then parse that page for the validation values, and then submit the form with those values and the data that I want to upload.

Is this approach viable? Where can I find information on something like this and the difficulties involved?

Comment: It certainly is viable. With Python + JavaScript + Selenium you pretty much have the full stack, so any web/HTTP problem should be solvable. It's usually just a question of how much of the UI you have to circumvent. Would need a URL or some source to be able to give specific advice.

Comment: It's a secured site so I can't give a URL. I'll see if there's some way I can provide usable source here, probably over the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight can be automated via Windows accessibility interfaces. The scope of this is too big for a stackoverflow post, but I suggest you have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms727247(v=vs.100).aspx

You can drill use UI Spy to drill down to control IDs and then use Python's COM interop to call the UI Automation APIs.

Comment: So in the end I was able to negotiate with the contractor for an easier to access interface, but that definitely looks useful, and will probably end up in other parts of my code.